# Facebook Graph API: I want to display user images album wise

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using graph-api provided by facebook. The version is 3.1.0.
My code is working fine but it displays all the images of user irrespective of the albums.

I want to change my code so that user can see only images of the album he/she has selected.

I mean images shall be displayed album wise.

My code below:

index.php

```
<?php
     /**********************************************************************
     * Plugin Name: Facebook Plugin                                        *
     * Plugin URI: http://www.picpixa.com/                                 *
     * Version: 1.0                                                        *
     * Author: Ashish Shah                                                 *
     * Description: Plugin To Import Images From User's Facebook Account   *
     *              as well as post the image of personalized product to   *
     *              his/her facebook account                               *
     **********************************************************************/
    session_start();
    include_once '/home/picpixa/wp-config.php';
    include_once "fbmain.php";

    ini_set("display_errors",1);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Facebook Images</title>      
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            .loader {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 9999;
                background: url('Images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
            }
        </style>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
            });
            function loader(){
                $('#load').show();
            }
            function loadExistingImages(){
                window.opener.$('#loader_img').show();
                result=null;
                window.opener.$('#fileupload').each(function () {
                        var that = this;
                        $.getJSON(this.action, function (result) {              
                            if (result && result.length) {
                                window.opener.$(that).fileupload('option', 'done')
                                    .call(that, null, {result: result});
                        //console.log('ss='+$('.table-striped tbody').find('.btn-danger').length);
                        if(window.opener.$('.table-striped tbody').find('.btn-danger').length>0){
                            window.opener.$('.coo-images-other-buttons').show();
                        }else{
                            window.opener.$('.coo-images-other-buttons').hide();  
                        }   
                            }
                            window.opener.$('#loader_img').hide();

                    if (window.opener.$('.table-striped tbody tr').length > 0)
                    {
                        window.opener.$('.table_tagline').show();
                    }
                        });
                    });             
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">$('#load').hide();</script>
    </head>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['copy']) && $_POST['facebook'])
        {
            $imgArray = $_POST['facebook'];

            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

            if(isset($current_user->ID) && trim($current_user->ID)!='' && trim($current_user->ID)!=0){
                $extraSessionStr = 'usr-'.md5($current_user->ID).'/';
                $user = $current_user->ID;
            }else{
                $sesstionId = session_id();
                $user = $sesstionId;
                $extraSessionStr = $sesstionId.'/';
            }

            $i=1;
            foreach ($imgArray as $img)
            {
                //$fileName=basename($img);
                $imgExt = pathinfo($img); //This will become an array with keys ('dirname','basename','extension','filename')
                $imageName = "FB-image";
                $fileName=$imageName.".".$imgExt['extension'];
                // Read file content
                $file_content = file_get_contents($img);

                //Check wether the file is exists or not rename the file if exists
                if(!file_exists('/home/picpixa/server/php/files/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName)){
                    file_put_contents('/home/picpixa/server/php/files/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName, $file_content);
                    //file_put_contents('/home/picpixa/server/php/thumbnails/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName, $file_content);
                    $i++;
                }
                else{
                    //echo "Entered in else part";
                    while(file_exists('/home/picpixa/server/php/files/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName)){
                        $fileName = (string) $imageName.$i.".".$imgExt['extension'];
                        //echo "Value of i: $i<br>Image name: $fileName<br>";
                        $i++;
                    }
                    file_put_contents('/home/picpixa/server/php/files/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName, $file_content);
                }

                //Get the image size
                $imgsize=get_headers($img,1);
                $imgsize = number_format(($imgsize["Content-Length"]/1024),2);

                /* To create thumbnail */

                // Max vert or horiz resolution
                $maxsize=80;

                // create new Imagick object
                $image = new Imagick($img); //"input_image_filename_and_location"

                // Resizes to whichever is larger, width or height
                if($image->getImageHeight() <= $image->getImageWidth())
                {
                    // Resize image using the lanczos resampling algorithm based on width
                    $image->resizeImage($maxsize,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Resize image using the lanczos resampling algorithm based on height
                    $image->resizeImage(0,$maxsize,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
                }

                // Set to use jpeg compression
                $image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
                // Set compression level (1 lowest quality, 100 highest quality)
                $image->setImageCompressionQuality(75);
                // Strip out unneeded meta data
                $image->stripImage();
                // Writes resultant image to output directory
                $image->writeImage('/home/picpixa/server/php/thumbnails/'.$extraSessionStr.$fileName); //"output_image_filename_and_location"
                // Destroys Imagick object, freeing allocated resources in the process
                $image->destroy();
            }
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //window.opener.$("#fileupload").append(div);
                    window.opener.$('tbody.files').find('tr').remove();
                    loadExistingImages();
                </script>
            <?php
            echo "<h2>The selected images have been moved.<br></h2>";
            echo "<h3>Please click on \"Proceed With Uploaded Images\" button to Proceed OR ";
            echo "Click on the \"Upload More Images\" Button to upload more images.</h3>";
        ?>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type='button' name='continue' value='Upload More Images' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='loader(); window.location.href="index.php";'>
                <input type='button' name='closeWindow' value='Proceed With Uploaded Images' class='btn btn-primary' onClick="window.close();">
            </div>
        <?php
            die();          
        }
        elseif (isset($_POST['copy']))
        {
            echo "<h2>You have not selected any image(s) to move.</h2><br><br>";
            echo "<h3>Please click on \"Close\" button to Close the window OR ";
            echo "Click on the \"Upload Images\" Button to upload images.</h3>";
        ?>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type='button' name='continue' value='Upload More Images' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='loader(); window.location.href="index.php";'>
                <input type='button' name='closeWindow' value='Close' class='btn btn-primary' onClick="window.close();">
            </div>
        <?php
            die();
        }
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt) {
                FB.ui({method: 'feed',
                    message: userPrompt,
                    link: hrefLink,
                    caption: hrefTitle,
                    picture: ''
                });
                //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
            }
            function publishStream() {
                streamPublish("Stream Publish", 'Checkout personalized products at www.picpixa.com. I found some of them are just awesome!', 'Checkout www.picpixa.com', 'http://www.picpixa.com', "Personalized Products");
            }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .box{
                margin: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #60729b;
                padding: 5px;
                width: 500px;
                height: 200px;
                overflow:auto;
                background-color: #e6ebf8;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            FB.init({
                appId: '',
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true // parse XFBML
            });
        </script>

    <body>
        <div id="load" class="loader"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <?php 
                        echo "User: $user";
                        if (!$user) { ?>
                            <h1>You have to login using Facebook Login Button to see your uploaded images.</h1>
                            <a class='btn btn-primary' href="<?= $loginUrl ?>" onClick='loader()'><img src="Images/login.png"></a>
                        <?php } //else { ?>
                                <!-- <a class='btn btn-primary' href="<?= $logoutUrl ?>" onClick='loader()'><img src="Images/logout.png"></a>-->
                        <?php //} ?>
                    </div>
                    <!-- all time check if user session is valid or not -->
                    <?php if ($user) { ?>
                        <form method="post" action="index.php">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <!-- Data retrived from user profile are shown here -->
                                <?php
                                    $i=0;
                                    $showBtn=false;
                                    $albums = $facebook->api("/me/albums");
                                    foreach($albums['data'] as $album){
                                        // get all photos for album
                                        $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album['id']}/photos");
                                        foreach($photos['data'] as $photo){
                                            /* if($i%5 == 0)
                                                {
                                                    echo "</tr>";
                                                    echo "<tr>";
                                                }*/
                                ?>
                                            <div class="baby_img">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="facebook_<?=$i;?>" name="facebook[]" value="<?php echo $photo['source']?>" class="styled" />
                                                <img src="<?php echo $photo['source']?>" width = "150px" height = "150px" class="img-responsive"/>
                                            </div>
                                <?php
                                            $i++;
                                            $showBtn=true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <?php
                                    if($showBtn){
                                        echo"<input type='submit' name='copy' value='Copy Selected Files' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='loader()'>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                                <input type='button' name='closeWindow' value='Close This Window' class='btn btn-primary' onClick="window.close();">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

can anyone help me please?

**Note:** It also gives script error of like: "Blocked loading mixed active content "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" and "ReferenceError: FB is not defined
FB.init({"

**Update:**

I have added one function to my code before closing the  tag.
Tha functio is as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function showAlbum(albumId){
                alert('Album Id'+albumId);
                var fbhtml = '';
                <?php
                    $albmId = albumId;
                    // get all photos for album
                    $i=0;
                    $photos = $facebook->api("/".$albmId."/photos");
                    foreach($photos['data'] as $photo){ ?>

                        fbhtml += '<div class="baby_img">';
                        fbhtml += '<input type="checkbox" id="facebook_<?php echo $i; ?>" name="facebook[]" value="<?php echo $photo["source"]; ?>" class="styled" />';
                        fbhtml += '<img src="<?php echo $photo["source"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" style="width:100px !important; height:100px !important;" />';
                        fbhtml += '</div>';

                <?php
                        $i++;
                        $showBtn=true;
                    }
                ?>
                $('#fbhtmlImage').html(fbhtml);
            }
        </script>
```

the function is working but I am not getting the desired output.
It is getting the images which are not in my album. And not getting the images which are in the album.

Comment: you have much of your html code between head and body, what are you doing ? read how to structure a proper html document .. also to resolve the fb initiate issue, use the javascript API imitate code provided by facebook in developers docs

Comment: ok then there is no use of that fb initiate and "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js". Right? Shall I remove it from my code?
And ofcource I will restructure my code.
Thanks for the suggestion....

Comment: @SyedQarib can you please help me to achieve my goal?
I want to display photos of only one album at a time.
User can select the album of which he want to display the photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved using ajax

```
function showAlbum(albumId){
                var fbhtml = '';
                $.ajax({                    
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "fbphotos.php",
                     data: { albumId: albumId }

                    }).done(function(response) {
                        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(response );

                        if(response['data'].length>0)
                        {
                            for(var x=0; x<response['data'].length; x++){
                                fbhtml += '<div class="baby_img">';
                                fbhtml += '<input type="checkbox" id="facebook_'+x+'" name="facebook[]" value="'+response['data'][x]['source']+'" class="styled" />';
                                fbhtml += '<img src="'+response['data'][x]['source']+'" class="img-responsive" style="width:100px !important; height:100px !important;" />';
                                fbhtml += '</div>';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fbhtml = 'There are no image(s) in this album.';
                        }

                        $('#fbhtmlImage').html(fbhtml);
                        $('#fbmodal-footer').show();
                        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
                });
            }
```

Comment: Hello 
I am facing a problem while importing photos from user timeline.
If user have uploaded multiple images, then those images are not being imported in my website. Otherwise all is working as expected.

Comment: The problem I have mentioned in the above comment is belongs to Facebook. It is the limitation of Open Graph API.
Ref.: I have posted this bug to facebook. Below is the bug report.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1465707063685271

Answer (score 0):

***This may serve as an answer to you but its more of my comment, but its quite long thats why I'm posting it here***

In this part of your code you already have what you want. The first loop iterates all the albums, so you can use the album.name to show the album and then you can pass the id (however you want, like on a link click) to show the corresponding photos.

Check my comments on your code here:

```
<?php
$albums = $facebook->api("/me/albums"); //This fetches all the albums
foreach($albums['data'] as $album){ //This loops every available album
    //Here you can get the name of the album
    //by $album['name']
    //and id by $album['id']

    //You can have links here
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="showAlbum('.$album['id'].')">'.$album['name'].'</a>';
}
?>
```

Here is the javascript function:

```
<script>
function showAlbum(albumId){
    // get all photos for album
    //use Js SDK here not the php SDK to load the images
    //If you want to still use the php sdk then make an ajax call
    //to the file which can return images of specific album by id
}
</script>
```

Comment: I know I am getting album Id and Name. But my concern is how can I give links to them.
shall I call a function on the click event or something like that?

Comment: thats what i have already written "***you can use the album.name to show the album and then you can pass the id (however you want, like on a link click) to show the corresponding photos***"

Comment: Thank you @syedQarib
But i am facing one issue...
I am pasting my function in below comment

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   function showAlbum(albumId){
    alert('function called');
    <?php
     // get all photos for album
     $i=0;
     $photos = $facebook->api("/".+albumId+"/photos");
     foreach($photos['data'] as $photo){
      echo '<div class="baby_img">
        <input type="checkbox" id="facebook_'.$i.'" name="facebook[]" value="'.$photo['source'].'" class="styled" />
        <img src="'.$photo['source'].'" class="img-responsive" style="width:100px !important; height:100px !important;" />
       </div>';
      $i++;
      $showBtn=true;
     }
    ?>
   }
  </script>

Comment: I have added the update function in the question in the Update: section.
Can you please check it... It is not getting the images from the album... In face not from my account...

Comment: Hello syedQarib,
I am facing a problem while importing photos from user timeline.
If user have uploaded multiple images, then those images are not being imported in my website. Otherwise all is working as expected.